# Contouring with cliff faces in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, contour

I am trying to create some contour lines that are around cliff faces.  What is the best way to create contour lines that are effected by cliff faces and is there a way to automatically draw the cliff faces?

I've tried using the Contour with barriers tool in ArcGIS but can't seem to get it to work.  I've downloaded the DEM Raster and can produce contours from that, just can't take it to the next step where the contours are effected by barriers.

I'm using both ArcGIS and QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.